# How to append to an existing SQL table with pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I have an existing SQL table with 8 columns. Now I also have a DataFrame with 2 columns. These 2 columns have the same name as the first 2 of the existing SQL table. Im trying to append my df to the existing SQL table. So for the first 2 columns I need it to append the data of my df and for the last 6 I need it to write None or NaN or 0.

This is my code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_2_columns = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([ls_meet_id]), 
                                columns=['ID', 'Value'])
                                                    
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pw}@localhost/{db}"
                        .format(user="root",
                                pw="*****.",
                                db="*****"))
# insert into table
df_2_columns.to_sql(my_table, con = engine, if_exists = 'append', chunksize = 1000)
```

When I run above I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: Empty data passed with indices specified.
```

Im sure it has to do with the fact that my df contains data of just 2 column while my eisting sql table contains data of 8 columns... How can this be fixed?

Comment: off the cuff, I think you should try sqlalchemy, to update the specific columns.

Comment: @sammywemmy Like what you mean? Can you show by code? Why is that better then appending?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use pandas.merge function, just in the case you have common fields between both tables, an ID fields, for instance or another field in common.

In that case

`margedDF = df_2_columns.merge({sql_df}, on={common_field}, how=outer)`

{sql_df} (or whatever is called it your sql table after converting it to dataframe)
{common_field} (the common field between both dataframes)

This will result as a new dataframe with columns in sql table and pandas dataframe.